# Django Girls tutorial "no module found" error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm following the Django girls tutorial. [ https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/ ]. At the URLs section of the tutorial, my server doesn't restart. Instead, I get this error:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.    <locals>.wrapper at 0x10f842048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,  
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/veryNewSite/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
path('', include('blog.urls')),
File "/Users/Aaron/Desktop/dev./Django/practice/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you wrote an `__init__.py` file in the `blog` module?

Answer (score 1):

Could be either of the following:

You don't have a `urls.py` file in your `blog` application.

...or...

You are missing an `__init__.py` file in your `blog` application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have both in my blog application. `__init__.py` is empty though.

Comment: That’s fine...could you supply your urls.py as well as you project directory structure...

Comment: Alright, I'm a little new to all this Micheal. How do I supply the urls.py and the project directory structure exactly?

Comment: @ShadowQ Inside your `blog` application, there should be a file named `urls.py` with your `urlpatterns` inside. Your directory structure can just be a screenshot if you find that easier just so I can see the folders and files you have inside your Django project...

Comment: that's everything. couldn't figure out how to get a file on here and it's not on GitHub. So here it is.      https://imgur.com/a/eVxSWoA